# How do I wrangle python lookups: make.up.a.dot.separated.name.and.use.it.until.destroyed = 777

Tags: python, namespaces, lookup

I'm a Python newbie with a very particular itch to experiment with Python's dot-name-lookup process.  How do I code either a class or function in "make.py" so that these assignment statements work succesfully?

```
import make

make.a.dot.separated.name = 666
make.something.else.up = 123
make.anything.i.want = 777
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Make:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self.__dict__[name] = Make()
        return self.__dict__[name]

make = Make()

make.a.dot.separated.name = 666
make.anything.i.want = 777

print make.a.dot.separated.name
print make.anything.i.want
```

The special `__getattr__` method is called when a named value isn't found. The line `make.anything.i.want` ends up doing the equivalent of:

```
m1 = make.anything    # calls make.__getattr__("anything")
m2 = m1.i             # calls m1.__getattr__("i")
m2.want = 777
```

The above implementation uses these calls to `__getattr__` to create a chain of `Make` objects each time an unknown property is accessed. This allows the dot accesses to be nested arbitrarily deep until the final assignment at which point a real value is assigned.

### [Python documentation - customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access):

> #### `object.__getattr__(self, name)`
>
> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for `self`). `name` is the attribute name. This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception.
>
> Note that if the attribute is found through the normal mechanism, `__getattr__()` is not called. (This is an intentional asymmetry between `__getattr__()` and `__setattr__()`.) This is done both for efficiency reasons and because otherwise `__getattr__()` would have no way to access other attributes of the instance. Note that at least for instance variables, you can fake total control by not inserting any values in the instance attribute dictionary (but instead inserting them in another object). See the `__getattribute__()` method below for a way to actually get total control in new-style classes.
>
> #### `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`
>
> Called when an attribute assignment is attempted. This is called instead of the normal mechanism (i.e. store the value in the instance dictionary). `name` is the attribute name, `value` is the value to be assigned to it.
>
> If `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should not simply execute `self.name = value` — this would cause a recursive call to itself. Instead, it should insert the value in the dictionary of instance attributes, e.g., `self.__dict__[name] = value`. For new-style classes, rather than accessing the instance dictionary, it should call the base class method with the same name, for example, `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

Comment: Is there somewhere we can read on the `dict` attribute and the way this code sample works?

Comment: @John Kugelman, I am in awe of the clean elegant simplicity of your answer.  Simply beautiful.

Comment: @blindvic, Python allows for clean elegant simplicity but does not guarantee it!  As the old saying goes, "a Real Programmer can write FORTRAN in any language."