# Python 2.7: variable names with dots

Tags: python, variables

I need a solution to define Python 2.7 variable names with dots like this:

```
myvar.one.two = 12
```

Here I found a nice solution: [How do I wrangle python lookups: make.up.a.dot.separated.name.and.use.it.until.destroyed = 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602745/how-do-i-wrangle-python-lookups-make-up-a-dot-separated-name-and-use-it-until-d/43821925#43821925)

But I can't define the folowing variable names:

```
myvar.one.two = 12
myvar.one.two.three = 123
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'three'
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: errr why don't you use myvar_one_two_three ?

Comment: Or just put those in a string and use a dictionary

Comment: Or give them more sensible names.

Comment: I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); maybe if you explained the problem you were actually trying to solve there's a better way.

Comment: Please note that Kugleman's solution doesn't generalise in the way you would like. He creates two variables, `make.a.dot.separated.name` and `make.anything.i.want`. No matter what the latter name suggests, and unlike what you have attempted, none of the names can be derived from others using his approach.

Answer (score 0):

The error code os correct Because Under myvar.one.two you placed 12 which is an int. Python is dynamic typed so you can create attributes of objects even if there aren't declared in the object. But when you store an int under `two` you have an integer object with all of its attributes and methods. The basic types are inmutable and you can't add attributes to them so adding a `two.three` will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library which could let you create and access dictionaries with the dot notation - https://github.com/cdgriffith/Box
Agree with @Guil23 that you should just use underscores instead.
Or if you have very complicated and structured data, use either a combination of [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or just plain old classes.